# How to update the driver version so I can run my Xamarin app?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-emulator, driver

I created a Xamarin.Forms Mobile App project.

I tried to run the Android emulator but I get the below error message and the the emulator only shows the Android home screen with no way to open the app.

> Your GPU driver information:
>
> GPU#1
> Make: 8086
> Model: Intel(R) HD Graphics
> Device ID: 0046
>
> Some users have experienced emulator stability issues with this driver version. As a result, we are selecting a compatibility renderer. Please check with your manufacturer to see if there is an updated driver available.

How do I fix this so that the emulator runs properly.

Comment: this is a basic PC user question, not a programming question.

Comment: @Jason so where do I put this question. Also, do you know the answer.

Comment: SuperUser.com has numerous posts about how to update a driver.  Generally you can just run Windows Update to do this